# pandas split by last delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, delimiter

I have the following column in a dataframe with different outputs:

```
col1
MLB|NBA|NFL
MLB|NBA
NFL|NHL|NBA|MLB
```

I would like to use the split function to split the column by the last pipe always so something like this:

```
col1           col2
MLB|NBA        NFL
MLB            NBA
NFL|NHL|NBA    MLB
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With `Series.str.rsplit`, limiting the number of splits.

```
df['col1'].str.rsplit('|', n=1, expand=True).rename(columns=lambda x: f'col{x + 1}')
```

If the above throws you a SyntaxError, it means you're on a python version older than 3.6 (shame on you!). Use instead

```
df.col1.str.rsplit('|', 1, expand=True)\
  .rename(columns=lambda x: 'col{}'.format(x + 1))

          col1 col2
0      MLB|NBA  NFL
1          MLB  NBA
2  NFL|NHL|NBA  MLB
```

---

There's also the faster loopy `str.rsplit` equivalent.

```
pd.DataFrame(
    [x.rsplit('|', 1) for x in df['col1'].tolist()], 
    columns=['col1', 'col2']
) 
          col1 col2
0      MLB|NBA  NFL
1          MLB  NBA
2  NFL|NHL|NBA  MLB
```

---

P.S., yes, the second solution is faster:

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 100000, ignore_index=True)

%timeit df['col1'].str.rsplit('|', n=1, expand=True)
%timeit pd.DataFrame([x.rsplit('|', 1) for x in df['col1'].tolist()])

473 ms ± 13.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
128 ms ± 1.29 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: The list comprehension is faster? Before I set up a proper test case for this, I assume you're stating that from some previous example or your own experience.

Comment: @roganjosh see my edit? From previous experience, most pandas str functions are just for convenience and not performance.

Comment: But that also constructs the DF at the same time, so it's even more shocking! Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: df['Label'].str.rsplit('|', 1, expand = True).rename(lambda x: f'Label{x+1}', axis = 1)

this is what i have but i get a syntax error? around the x+1?

Comment: @roganjosh That's CPython for you. All those layers of overhead in the pandas internals are the culprit really.

Comment: @coldspeed yeah but that's a  _bad_ hit. I'll be sure to scrutinise this more closely in future.

Comment: df['Label'].str.rsplit('|', 1, expand = True)\
        .rename(lambda x: 'Label{}'.format(x+1),axis = 1)

this throws me a Type Error: rename() got an unexpected keyword argument "axis"

Comment: @skimchi1993 Dude! Upgrade your pandas version PLEASE. See my edit. This is the last time I edit to accommodate your version issues :-(