# Replace cell values in each row of pandas column using for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, replace

Please, help me understand my error.
I'm trying to change one column in my `.csv` file.
I have `.csv` file as following:

```
sku,name,code  
k1,aaa,886  
k2,bbb,898  
k3,ccc,342  
k4,ddd,503  
k5,eee,401
```

I want to replace "k" symbol with the "_" symbol in the "sku" column.
I wrote the code:

```
import sys  
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np  
import datetime  

df = pd.read_csv('cat0.csv')  

for r in df['sku']:  
    r1 = r.replace('k', '_')  
    df['sku'] = r1  

print (df)
```

But the code inserts the last value in every row of the "sku" column. So I get:

```
  sku name  code
0  _5  aaa   886
1  _5  bbb   898
2  _5  ccc   342
3  _5  ddd   503
4  _5  eee   401
```

I want to get as following:

```
  sku name  code
0  _1  aaa   886
1  _2  bbb   898
2  _3  ccc   342
3  _4  ddd   503
4  _5  eee   401
```

Comment: The numerical value of `sku` matches the index +1 in your example. Is that guaranteed? I have a feeling that could be exploited to give a faster solution than if it's not guaranteed.

Comment: Without a for loop, you can do `df['sku'] = df['sku'].str.replace('k', '_')`, it is vectorized.

Comment: @Jan be careful with the assertion that it is vectorized. I only say that because [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50993283/4799172) shocked me quite a bit yesterday.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `str.replace` on the whole column:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = """sku,name,code  
k1,aaa,886  
k2,bbb,898  
k3,ccc,342  
k4,ddd,503  
k5,eee,401"""

file = StringIO(data)

df = pd.read_csv(file)
df['sku'] = df['sku'].str.replace('k', '_')

print(df)
```

This yields

```
  sku name  code  
0  _1  aaa     886
1  _2  bbb     898
2  _3  ccc     342
3  _4  ddd     503
4  _5  eee     401
```

Answer (score 5):

As @Jan mentioned, **doing it by using `df['sku'] = df['sku'].str.replace('k', '_')` is the best/quickest way to do this.**

However, to understand why you are getting the results you are and to present a way as close to how you were doing it as possible, you'd do:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'sku':["k1", "k2", "k3", "k4", "k5"], 
        'name': ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee"], 
        'code':[886, 898,342,503,401]
    }, columns =["sku", "name", "code"]
)

for i, r in enumerate(df['sku']):  
    r1 = r.replace('k', '_')
    df.at[i, 'sku'] = r1
```

**Which gives:**

```
  sku name  code
0  _1  aaa   886
1  _2  bbb   898
2  _3  ccc   342
3  _4  ddd   503
4  _5  eee   401
```

**In your code...**

```
for r in df['sku']:  
    r1 = r.replace('k', '_')
```

**...the issue is here:**

```
    df['sku'] = r1
```

You are broadcasting your results to the entire column rather than just the row you are working on.