# How to get rid of the first column in the csv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, replace

[Replace cell values in each row of pandas column using for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51001165/replace-cell-values-in-each-row-of-pandas-column-using-for-loop/62682418?noredirect=1#comment110849311_62682418)

I want the same output as they have in that link but without the 01234 in the first column

current output according to that code:

```
  sku name  code
0  _1  aaa   886
1  _2  bbb   898
2  _3  ccc   342
3  _4  ddd   503
4  _5  eee   401
```

I want the output to be:

```
sku name  code  
 _1  aaa     886
 _2  bbb     898
 _3  ccc     342
 _4  ddd     503
 _5  eee     401
```

Also if I want to change just the 'bbb' to 'bab' just that one string in the whole column, how should I?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to write the dataframe to CSV without the index column?

Answer (score 1):

The `01234` is the index for the `DataFrame`, as below set `index=False`.

Try:

```
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

**Edit for answer # 2:**

Code below will do the replacement:

```
df['name'] = df['name'].replace('bbb', 'bab')
```

Answer (score 0):

### Edit for answer: making it more 'pandorable'

Set the index to be `sku` and changing all **bbb** to **bab** :

`df = df.set_index('sku').replace('bbb','bab')`